# How to parse Dictionary value and pass into class modal in swift?

Tags: arrays, json, swift, dictionary

My JSON data

```
{
 "addon_items" : [
                     {
                      "aname" : "",
                      "id" : "2588",
                      "name" : "Plain Nan",
                      "order" : "1",
                      "aid" : "259",
                      "Sub_Add_Items" : "",
                      "icon" : "",
                      "status" : "1",
                      "next" : "0",
                      "price" : "0.60"
                     },
                     {
                      "aname" : "",
                      "id" : "2589",
                      "name" : "Pitta Bread",
                      "order" : "2",
                      "aid" : "259",
                      "Sub_Add_Items" : "",
                      "icon" : "",
                      "status" : "1",
                      "next" : "0",
                      "price" : "0.00"
                    }

                   ],

 "addon" : {
             "description" : "Please choose your Nan bread",
             "aname" : "",
             "id" : "259",
             "icon" : "",
             "limit" : "1",
             "special_addon" : "",
             "next" : "165"
           }
 }
```

I created three class models named AddOnResponse, AddOn, AddOnItems like this:

**AddOnResponse class model**

```
class AddOnResponse {

var addon: [String: AnyObject]?
var addonitems: Array<AnyObject>?

init(addon:[String: AnyObject]?,addonitems: Array<AnyObject>?){
    self.addon = addon
    self.addonitems = addonitems
 }
}
```

**AddOn class model**

```
class AddOn {


var id: Int?
var icon: String?
var desc: String?
var limit: Int?
var next: Int?
var aname: String?
var specialaddon: Int?

init(id: Int?,icon: String?,desc: String?,limit: Int?,next: Int?,aname: String?,specialaddon: Int?){

    self.id = id
    self.icon = icon
    self.desc = desc
    self.limit = limit
    self.next = next
    self.aname = aname
    self.specialaddon = specialaddon

  }
 }
```

**AddOnItems class model**

```
class AddOnItems {


var id: Int?
var aid: Int?
var name: String?
var price: Int?
var order: Int?
var status: Int?
var next: Int?
var aname: String?
var subaddItems: Int?
var icon: String?

init(id: Int?,aid: Int?,name: String?,price: Int?,order: Int?,status: Int?,next: Int?,aname: String?,subaddItems: Int?,icon: String?){
    self.id = id
    self.aid = aid
    self.name = name
    self.price = price
    self.order = order
    self.status = status
    self.next = next
    self.aname = aname
    self.subaddItems = subaddItems
    self.icon = icon
   }
 }
```

Now I am fetching my JSON data using Alamofire but when passing data to addon model using object I am getting nil value.

```
    var addonResponses = [AddOnResponse]()

    Alamofire.request(.GET, myAddOnUrl)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON
        {   response in
            switch response.result
            {
            case .Success:
                if let value = response.result.value{
                    let json = JSON(value)
                    print(json)
                    print(json["addon"].arrayValue)

                  let addOnRes = AddOnResponse(addon: json["addon"].object as? [String : AnyObject],
                                 addonitems: json["addon_items"].arrayObject)
              print(addOnRes.addon)
```

The `addon` and `addonitems` data are coming here in class model. Now when I am passing data to the Addon modal here its getting nil..

```
                for (_,content) in json["addon"]{

                        let addon = AddOn(id: Int(content["id"].stringValue),
                                          icon: content["icon"].string,
                                          desc: content["description"].string,
                                          limit: Int(content["limit"].stringValue),
                                          next: Int(content["next"].stringValue),
                                          aname: content["aname"].string,
                                          specialaddon: Int(content["special_addon"].stringValue)
                                         )
                            print(addon.desc) /// nil value
                     }
```

so how to parse the addon all data and pass to class model..

Comment: Do not add your solution to your *question*. Post it as an *answer* instead.

Comment: ok...........@EricD